# ranking server implementation nosql together with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, nosql

I'm required to implement an assignment which requires to use mysql with nosql together.
I've already implemented the mysql table. However, I'm not sure about the architecture of nosql.

The server requires to output the most successful 100 person by day, the day before(yesterday),week and all time according to experience.

The mysql table has 2 tables, `user` & `score`.

`user` table has the following fields ; `user_id(BIGINT)` & `full_name(BIGINT)`

`score` table has the following fields ; `user_id(BIGINT)`, `level(INT)`, `total_exp(BIGINT)`, `today_exp(BIGINT)`, `weekly_exp(BIGINT)`

For better performance, I should also be using no-sql solutions. However, I'm not sure about the architecture of no-sql.

I'm currently thinking to create mongodb tables; `ranking_all`, `ranking_today`, `ranking_week`, `ranking_yesterday` which has indexes from 0 to 99.

I'll update the mongodb table whenever an active user plays and gain experience accordingly.

However, there are some points that I'm not sure of. In this system, if the active user base increases, the cost of overall updating mysql & mongodb tables increases.

So, is overall architecture good in terms of performance ?

Any ideas to change/improve the design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious why you have to use NoSQL?

Why not just store the rankings in MySQL?  No need to introduce a new dependency/a new system to your software stack.

Your description doesn't seem to need any of the advantages of a NoSQL database.  It just sounds like pre-processing some rankings and then writing them somewhere.  I would just write to MySQL.

Comment: the first reason is that the data retrieval and insertions for pre-processed nosql solutions performs great. the second reason is that I'm required to do that. It's a must use requirement :)

Comment: If it's a requirement, then I would recommend Mongo. It has a ton of momentum right now (maybe the most active NoSQL community) and it has a lot of flexibility with the query language. You can also pump out raw data to it and then run map/reduce jobs in the background to get aggregates. With Mongo, I would recommend starting with a simple three node replica set and see how that works for you. There is a bit of a learning curve, but it's not too bad. =)